# Выводить уведомление на экране блокировки

Tags: android

Есть сервис, который запускает аудио в фоновом режиме и выводит уведомление в шторку. На Android < 8 если не ошибаюсь (сейчас не могу проверить) на экране блокировки отображается уведомление, а на Android 9 и выше не отображается. Как выводить уведомление на экран блокировки на Android 9 и выше?

На телефоне Mi9T с Android 10 при тестировании не отображается уведомление на экране блокировки. Уведомления из других приложений выводятся.

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {
    public static Context context;
    boolean isPlay = false;
    String stream;
    String AUDIO;
    String img;
    Notification notification;

    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    public static final String KEY_STREAM = PlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_STREAM";
    public static final String KEY_AUDIO = PlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_AUDIO";
    public static final String KEY_IMG = PlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_IMG";

    private void showNotification() {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

        int notifyId = 1;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Играет: " + AUDIO)
                    .setContentText("Открыть список")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setDeleteIntent(pCloseIntent)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
            startForeground(PlayerConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
        }

        if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) && (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)) {
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Играет: " + AUDIO)
                    .setContentText("Открыть список")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "Стоп", pCloseIntent)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
            startForeground(PlayerConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            String channelID = "cAUDIOID";
            CharSequence cannelName = "AUDIO Channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, cannelName, importance);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(PlayerService.this, channelID)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("Играет: " + AUDIO)
                    .setColor(Color.RED)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setChannelId(channelID)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "Стоп", pCloseIntent)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
            startForeground(PlayerConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        context = this;
        this.stream = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_STREAM);
        this.AUDIO = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_AUDIO);
        this.img = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_IMG);

        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPlay = true;

            showNotification();

            AUDIOPlayer.startPlayer(stream, this);

        } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPlay = false;

            Intent brIntent = new Intent(PlayerActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);

            brIntent.putExtra(PlayerActivity.SERVICE_PARAM, 0);

            sendBroadcast(brIntent);

            AUDIOPlayer.stopPlayer();
            stopForeground(true);
            PlayerActivity.isPlay = false;
            stopSelf();
        }

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        AUDIOPlayer.stopPlayer();
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте что-то такое: `notificationChannel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC`. И проверьте, что оно на не Xiomi делает. Возможно это проблема связанная с прошивкой производителя.

Comment: Попробую, спасибо.